# Upload files to Google Drive from Google forms file uploads renamed with field name (string value) collected from the Form Response?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, drive

This code currently takes the unique ID from the form response and puts it as the folder name where all the uploaded file goes to. I want to change the code so that it takes a text field from the Google Form response for organized view, such as First Name_Last Name.

```
const PARENT_FOLDER_ID = "2ih2384723847234878h23jkbi2j3b4ijb23i4bhwed34f";

const initialize = () => {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
};

const onFormSubmit = ({ response } = {}) => {
  try {
    // Get a list of all files uploaded with the response
    const files = response
      .getItemResponses()
      // We are only interested in File Upload type of questions
      .filter(
        (itemResponse) =>
          itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD"
      )
      .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
      // The response includes the file ids in an array that we can flatten
      .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);

    if (files.length > 0) {
      // Each form response has a unique Id
      const subfolderName = response.getId();
      const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
      const subfolder = parentFolder.createFolder(subfolderName);
      files.forEach((fileId) => {
        // Move each file into the custom folder
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(subfolder);
      });
    }
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the names are the first and second questions.

```js
/* ... */

const n = response.getItemResponses().slice(0, 2)
const fn = n[0].getResponse();
const ln = n[1].getResponse();

/* ... */

const subfolderName = `${fn}_${ln}`;

/* ... */
```